# Adding action listener to a button mentioned in XML

Tags: java, xml, swing, compiler-errors, jbutton

I tried below code to add `ActionListener` to a `JButton` in XML using `DocumentBuilderfactory`.

I'm getting an error: `Duplicate local variable element` at the line where I put a comment below.

But if I rename one of those variables then how do I link this actionListener to the button of ID which is present in XML?

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException{
     try{
        XMLDecoder xmlDecoder = new XMLDecoder(new FileInputStream("ActionListener.xml"));
        Object frame = xmlDecoder.readObject();
        xmlDecoder.close();
        System.out.println("siri");
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("ActionListener.xml"));
        Element element = doc.getElementById("Id");
        String attrValue = element.getAttribute("string");
        JButton element = new JButton("attrValue"); // <-- error happens here
        element.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.out.println("Its a success");
            } 
        });
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I'm getting an error"* What error? Always copy/paste error and exception output! BTW: change `System.out.println(ex);` to `ex.printStackTrace(); System.out.println(ex);` General tips: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a common problem w/ code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Just as the exception tells you, you have a duplicated variable in your code.
That means you try to declare a new variable that has the exact same name as another one.

In your code, you have two variables called `element`:

```
Element element = doc.getElementById("Id");
JButton element = new JButton("attrValue");
```

Rename one of those to fix your issue.

Next, this part of your code seems shady:

```
Element element = doc.getElementById("Id");
String attrValue = element.getAttribute("string");
JButton button = new JButton("attrValue"); //Note I changed the variable name
```

The variable `attrValue` string value is never used, as you set a constant string value "attrValue" as your JButton label.
You probably want to write:

```
JButton button = new JButton(attrValue);
```

Plus, you create a brand new JButton and add an actionListener but it is not displayed as you never add it to a view.

Comment: The JButton is mentioned in the XML file. I want to add actionlistener to that particular JButton. Don't want to add a new JButton in swing.